# Odd Apache2 Zombie Mode and Failure

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, apache2, ubuntu-18.04, digital-ocean

For past few day's I been having some odd issues. This all starter this past Sunday, as per the system logs around 4:00 AM on Sunday morning.

I noticed inability to connect to my site and all requests were being timed out. I logged into my DigitalOcean dashboard and for the specific Droplet noticed crazy CPU usage.

On average the CPU usage is below 1.0% but when this whole fiasco starter the CPU usage was sitting at 30 ~ 40%.

So I decided to roll back to a Backup created by DigitalOcean, I rolled to  7 days Backup, ran into the same issues few hours later. Also backed up to 21 days Backup, also the same problem.

So after 24 hours, Apache2 failed again. I went ahead and rebooted the server, but I don't think this will fix it.

As the title goes, when I login into the server via SSH I'm greeted with

**=> There are 7 zombie processes.**

But when I run **top** it displays **0 zombie** and running

```
ps axo stat,ppid,pid,comm | grep -w defunct
```

Also does not return any results.

My server specs:

- 2GB vRAM
- 2 vCPU
- Ubuntu 18.10
- Kernel 4.18.0.22-generic
- Apache 2.4.39
- PHP 7.2.19

Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you add output of **ps aux | grep 'Z'** also.